# does jQuery Mobile has an autocomplete plugin?

Tags: autocomplete, jquery-mobile

I am looking for a plugin that provides the autocomplete feature using jQuery Mobile? Similar to what we have in jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing specific for jQuery Mobile, no. However, you should be able to use other jQuery plugins just fine. For example, I used the standard jQuery UI autocomplete function in a recent jQuery Mobile project (the only tweak required was to over-ride some CSS).

Comment: ok. I will give this one more try and update. UI was not smooth when I used jQuery UI's autocomplete in jQuery mobile.